# Insert into inside cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CODE
    FROM   T1
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        INSERT  INTO T4(TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3)
        SELECT  T2.TEXT1, T2.TEXT2, T3.TEXT3
        FROM    T2,
                T3
        WHERE   T2.ID = T3.ID
        AND     T2.CODE = T1.CODE
    ) AS T
```

When using executing this query I get this error:

> A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause.

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*

What I was planning to achieve was simulate a WHILE..LOOP. 
Looping through all the CODEs in T1 and for each CODE get the TEXT fields from T2 and T3 (joining them with the ID) and insert them into table T4.

I am trying to separate the inserts by CODE because both tables have a large amount of data and I was trying to improve performance (maybe?!)

Comment: Why are you trying to do an insert like that?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Something like for each ID in T1 table, insert the TEX1, 2 and 3 into FINAL table.

Comment: Are you simply trying to do an insert, or do an insert and get the results afterwards?   That syntax is just confusing, and your explanation doesn't quite sync with the code you've written

Comment: With your outer Cross Apply, you get a list of all the ID from table T1; wheither or not that they have in equivalent part in T2/T3 that have been inserted.  I'm not sure that this is really what you want to get but you didn't describe the exact result that you want to get at the end; therefore is impossible to tell you if a simpler solution exists.

Comment: That is exactly what my answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a guess

```
INSERT  INTO FINAL (TEXT1   , TEXT2   , TEXT3)
SELECT  DISTINCT    T2.TEXT1, T2.TEXT2, T3.TEXT3
  FROM  T1
  JOIN  T2
   on   T2.ID = T1.ID
  JOIN  T3
    on  T3.VALUE = T2.VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're attempting to do. The language will not allow you. To set the stage, I created the following 3 tables

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Final
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
,   text1 varchar(50) NOT NULL
,   text2 varchar(50) NOT NULL
,   text3 varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Chain
(
    ID int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Chained
(
    ID int NOT NULL
,   Foo int NOT NULL
);
```

Just to demo where the `OUTPUT` clause goes, we will insert 4 rows and see the nice pretty INSERTED virtual table and the associated ID values.

```
-- Works
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.Final
    (
        text1
    ,   text2
    ,   text3
    )
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.*
    SELECT
        D.t1
    ,   D.t2
    ,   D.t3    
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            ('A', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('D', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('G', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('J', 'B', 'C')
    ) D (t1,t2,t3);
```

Now, if I perform the following statement, it will work fine. However, if I neglect the INSERT just to visually inspect what I want to put into the table, SQL Server will raise the following error

> A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.

```
-- Comment out the insert portion to generate
-- A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.
INSERT INTO
    dbo.Chain
(
    ID
)
SELECT
    X.ID
FROM
(
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.Final
    (
        text1
    ,   text2
    ,   text3
    )
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.*
    SELECT
        D.t1
    ,   D.t2
    ,   D.t3    
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            ('A', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('D', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('G', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('J', 'B', 'C')
    ) D (t1,t2,t3)
) x
```

But, you want to go the extra mile and APPLY, or JOIN the results of that virtual table with something else and that's not going to fly.

> A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed on either side of a JOIN or APPLY operator.

I suppose it's just one level of complexity too much.

```
-- Now, try the same bit except we use the derived table as a JOIN/APPLY
-- Can't fix what's not supported 
-- A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed on either side of a JOIN or APPLY operator.
INSERT INTO
    dbo.Chained
(
    ID
,   Foo
)
SELECT
    X.ID
,   D.foo
FROM
(
    VALUES
    (1)
) D(Foo)
CROSS APPLY
(
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.Final
    (
        text1
    ,   text2
    ,   text3
    )
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.*
    SELECT
        D.t1
    ,   D.t2
    ,   D.t3    
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            ('A', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('D', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('G', 'B', 'C')
        ,   ('J', 'B', 'C')
    ) D (t1,t2,t3)
) x;
```

If you really need something like that, then you'll have to break it out into separate statements.